# How to set interface IP in requests?

Tags: python, python-2.7

My server has 3 IPs, how I can set interface IP in my python request?

My current script:

```
import requests

headers = {
               'User-Agent'  :  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0',
               'Accept-Language'  :  'en-en,en;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
               'Connection'  :  'keep-alive',
               'RequestTarget': 'AJAXService',
               'Origin'      :  'http://m.site.com',
               'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
               'Accept': '*/*',
               'Referer': 'http://m.site.com/'
               }

cookies = {
    'ASP.NET_SessionId': 'py5beylwcovqwmikg0tputgn',
    'lng': '4'
    }

r = requests.get("http://httpbin.org/get", cookies=cookies, headers=headers)

print r.text
```

But this script use only default IP but I need change it each time.